# is there a way to check the next object inside NSArray in a for..in loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this NSArray:

```
NSArray* temp=[[NSArray alloc]
initWithObjects:@"one",@"five",@"two",nil];

for(NSString* obj in temp){ 
    NSLog(@"current item:%@ Next item is:%@",obj, ***blank***);
}
```

What needs to replace `blank`?  Do I need to know the upcoming object?

Comment: Fast enumeration is a solution to a single specific problem, if you need more complex behaviors I believe you have to fall back to a good old regular loop and simply use index+1 to get the next object.

Comment: You can fetch the data on the basis of index in a normal for loop. If [temp count]>(currentIndex+1) then fetch data for [temp objectAtIndex:[currentIndex+1]];

Comment: @rmaddy - Yes, thats why I've mentioned If [temp count]>(currentIndex+1) :)

Comment: @RenoJones Oops - reading comprehension failure - sorry ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This only works if your objects are unique (i. e. there are no identical objects in the array):

```
id nxt = nil;
int nxtIdx = [temp indexOfObject:idx] + 1;
if (nxtIdx < temp.count) {
    nxt = [temp objectAtIndex:nxtIdx];
}
NSLog(@"current item:%@ Next item is:%@", obj, nxt);
```

But in my opinion, this is a hack. Why not use a normal for loop with the index of the object:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.count; i++) {
    id obj = [temp objectAtIndex:i];
    id next = (i + 1 < temp.count) ? [temp objectAtIndex:i + 1] : nil;
}
```

Or (**recommended**) enumerate it using a block

```
[temp enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    id next = nil;
    if (idx + 1 < temp.count) {
        next = [temp objectAtIndex:idx + 1];
    }
}];
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Try using an `NSEnumerator`.

Code:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [temp objectEnumerator];
id obj;
while (obj = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    if ([enumerator nextObject] == nil) {
       NSLog(@"This is the last object: %@", obj);
       break;
    }
    NSLog(@"current item:%@ Next item is:%@", obj, [enumerator nextObject]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with fast enumeration without a few lines of extra code (deriving the index, adding to it, checking its still in bounds).

You could enumerate using a block and add one to the `idx` parameter, but a better design (where you wouldn't risk or have to check for out of bounds exceptions) would be to remember the *previous* object instead, which will be nil on your first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of your current object and look at the next with something similar to:

```
NSArray* temp=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"five",@"two",nil];

for(NSString* obj in temp){

    if([temp count] < [temp indexOfObject:obj]+1)
    {
        NSLog(@"current item:%@ Next item is:%@",obj, [temp objectAtIndex:[temp indexOfObject:obj] + 1]);
    }

}
```

To me it can sometimes be easier to do a traditional for loop in this case to have access to your index variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using fast enumeration, this is the only way:

```
NSInteger index = [temp indexOfObject:obj];
if (index != NSNotFound && index < temp.count)
    NSObject nextObject = [temp objectAtIndex:(index + 1)];
```

Note the if, you'll want to make sure you get a valid index, and that adding one to it doesn't put you out of bounds.

Comment: This code is Wrong! If obj is located at index 9 in an array of 10 items (count=10) then nextObject is out of bounds! It does not exist! Do Use the accepted answer. Why don't you provide a complete answer?